# Pentesting a GWT application

Tags: security, owasp, penetration-testing

can you give me some information how to pen-test a GWT application. Is there any kind of pen testing document (like the owasp testing guide ) for GWT

Answer (score 0):

It's still all HTTP.  You don't need to approach it much differently than a non-GWT application, but you do need to familiarized yourself with the various vulnerabilities that have been found in GWT over the years and test for those few specific items.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [GWT-Penetration-Testing-Toolset](https://github.com/GDSSecurity/GWT-Penetration-Testing-Toolset).